# Can't deploy on heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I'm new on Heroku and trying to deploy my pet project here(Java/Spring). But when i do all i need to do i have rejection:

> Task :compileJava
> /tmp/build_910257bb_/src/main/java/pet_app/crypto/model/Role.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
> USER(Set.of(Permission.USER_RIGHTS)),
> symbol:   method of(Permission)
> location: interface Set
> /tmp/build_910257bb_/src/main/java/pet_app/crypto/model/Role.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
> ADMIN(Set.of(Permission.USER_RIGHTS, Permission.ADMIN_RIGHTS));

Here is full code of this enum :

```
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public enum Role {
    USER(Set.of(Permission.USER_RIGHTS)),
    ADMIN(Set.of(Permission.USER_RIGHTS, Permission.ADMIN_RIGHTS));

    private final Set<Permission> permissions;

    Role(Set<Permission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Set<Permission> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getPermissions().stream()
                .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

As i know, Set.of was added in java 9, maybe Heroku does not support it for some reason? Should i change my code in order to replace Set.of or maybe I can find something useful in Heroku settings( I searched but didn't found).
p.s. my project (in localhost) works fine, no errors with this interface or another parts of program

Comment: Do you have a `system.properties` file? You can specify the Java version you need like so: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version

Comment: Your answer helped me! Can you change it in a way so I can vote for it as a best answer?